# How to parse a string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, parsing

So the problem is I have a column that contains a snapshot:

```
<p>
<t8>xx</t8>
<s7>321</s7>
<s1>6</s1>
<s2>27</s2>
<s4>73</s4>
<t1>noemail@noemail.com</t1>
<t2>xxxxx</t2>
<t3>xxxxxx</t3>
<t11>xxxxxxxx</t11>
<t6>xxxxxxxx</t6>
<t7>12345</t7>
<t9>1234567890</t9>
</p>
```

I need to parse this string in MySQL so that I can count the number of times that noemail.com occurs.  I am not familiar with parsing so if you could please explain the best you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by removing searched substring and comparing the lengths. For example :

```
set @str = '<p>
<t8>xx</t8>
<s7>321</s7>
<s1>6</s1>
<s2>27</s2>
<s4>73</s4>
<t1>noemail@noemail.com</t1>
<t2>xxxxx</t2>
<t3>xxxxxx</t3>
<t11>xxxxxxxx</t11>
<t6>xxxxxxxx</t6>
<t7>12345</t7>
<t9>1234567890</t9>
</p>';

set @find = 'noemail@noemail.com';

select (length(@str) - length(replace(@str, @find, '')))/length(@find) AS NumberOfTimesEmailAppears;
```

I think there is sadly no more elegant solution (note that a database system is not designed to parse strings : this is most the job of a scripting language)